# Set $JAVA_HOME in eclipse but ANT Cannot Find Java Compiler

Tags: eclipse, ant, java-home

I add this line to `/home/{user}/.bashrc` file:

```
 export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk
```

but when I want to run an ant file in eclipse got this error:

```
BUILD FAILED
/home/bakish/Work/new/hadoop-0.20.2/build.xml:316: Unable to find a javac compiler;
com.sun.tools.javac.Main is not on the classpath.
Perhaps JAVA_HOME does not point to the JDK.
It is currently set to "/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre"
```

what should I do?

Thanks

Comment: don't forget to vote up the answer if it helped you

Answer (score 10, accepted):

go to preferences / java / installed jre's
-> add a new jre and select the location of your jre/jdk

Comment: It works, but if I add ANT jar files to jre/jdk it give same error

Comment: -> windows / preferences / ant / runtime -> add jars