# Ant "JAVA_HOME does not point to the JDK" - but it does

Tags: eclipse, ant, java

I cannot run my Ant build.xml since I updated to java 1.7.0_52 (or there about). I have been running it for years through Eclipse locally on my Windows 7 laptop - but with this latest jave jdk update somethings different (?).

```
BUILD FAILED
C:\workspace\WaterAspectsModel3\build.xml:329: Unable to find a javac compiler;
com.sun.tools.javac.Main is not on the classpath.
Perhaps JAVA_HOME does not point to the JDK.
It is currently set to "D:\Morten\Java\jdk1.7.0_52"
```

This is my jdk! So JAVA_HOME is pointing to a jdk (as is also clear from the error message). I have my JAVA_HOME with bin folder in my path as always. I've configured Eclipse - external tools configuration - with a JRE pointing to the same D:\Morten\Java\jdk1.7.0_52 (through "Separate JRE" setting). And I've tried a number of other configurations - all without luck.

I've been reading the tonnes of answers on lists here and other places and think I've tried all suggestions. Most seem to be cases where JAVA_HOME actually points to a jre and just needs to be corrected to jdk or there's a ";" in the path or something like that. None of these seem to apply in my case.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you have your `ANT_HOME` environment variable set? Is it also in `PATH`? That is system path.

Comment: How about printouts for `java -version` and `javac -version` from your lovely cmd.exe? And also what does `JAVA_HOME` tell you there?

Comment: Try `ant -version` as well.

Comment: Try the following command in a terminal: "%JAVA_HOME%\bin\javac". If the command does not exist that proves you don't have a JDK installed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set $JAVA\_HOME in eclipse but ANT Cannot Find Java Compiler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5297146/set-java-home-in-eclipse-but-ant-cannot-find-java-compiler)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The real message is that Ant can't find `com.sun.tools.javac.Main`.

Which, together with the fact that the latest "Sun" (Oracle) JDK is 1.7.0_13 (or maybe _14, but definitely not the "_52" that your install dir indicates), makes me think that you're not using a distribution that Ant recognizes. You can verify this by running `jar tvf $JAVA_HOME/lib/tools.jar`, and looking for that class.

The [Ant Manual](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javac.html) talks about ways to work with different compilers. Since I've only used "Sun" compilers, I'm afraid that I can't give you any pointers.

---

Edit: you could also try setting `fork="yes"` in your build file. This should run the compiler executable rather than trying to invoke the compiler class.

Comment: It's much more likely that the JAVA_HOME variable is pointing at a JRE instead of a JDK. There are two distributions of Java, only the "Java Development Kit" contains the **javac** command and other useful binaries used by developers

Comment: @MarkO'Connor - possibly, although the OP claims to have checked that multiple times, so I see no reason to argue otherwise, The presence (or absence) of `tools.jar` would be strong evidence either way. The thing that makes me think it might be something else is the version number of the installation directory.

Comment: THANKS parsifal! I'm not there yet but the "jar tvf tools.jar" clearly indicated that this was a tools.jar from a complete different project. Just uninstalling and re-installing my jdk.

Comment: @MortenGrum - unless you have a good reason to do otherwise, I recommend downloading the Oracle distribution: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html

Comment: SOLVED! Re-installing the jdk (to the one you recommended) did the trick! I seem to remember some time back getting a jdk without tools.jar and then some fool (undoubtedly me) seems to have picked the nearest tools.jar file and copied it in. Not too smart - and no wander I didn't find much help the the existing posts. THANKS for leading me to it!

Comment: Eclipse > WaterAspectsModel3 > Right-click > Properties > Java Build Path > Libraries > Add External Jar > ${someJDKDistributionOnYourDrive}/lib/tools.jar

worked for me.

Answer (score 40):

I was having the same message when running ANT through Eclipse.

**What worked for me:**

1. In Eclipse, access the menu: "Window -> Preferences";
2. Access "Ant -> Runtime", at the tree;
3. Access the Classpath tab;
4. Expand the "Global Entries" item;
5. Inside Global Entries, the path to `tools.jar` was wrong. It was pointing to an older version of Java;
6. I removed the wrong entry and added the correct one with "Add External Jars" button. It worked.

[image]

Comment: Thanks - it worked for me. tools.jar entry was missing. I got it fixed

Answer (score 11):

The solution 
"`Had to copy C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_10\lib\tools.jar to C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\ext`" from [here](http://forums.drftpd.org/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=2978) was great helpful and worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `JAVA_HOME\bin` to your `env PATH` .

Comment: No, `JAVA_HOME` should be the your `jdk` folder, the bin path should be in your `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: All this is in place - and has been for a while. ... JAVA_HOME to jdk root and bin path in PATH (checked a dozen times).

Answer (score 0):

Add JAVA_HOME to Eclipse-Preferences-Java-Build Path-Classpath Variables.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the unearthing,

I had the same problem, my solution doesn't need any modification in environment variables, and works for a recent JDK where the tools.jar can't be found.

Just go in the small down-arrow next to the ant run button
Then click "Configure external tools"
Then in JRE tab
Select a JDK installed on your computer, not a JRE, no problems if the selected JDK is not the same JDK/JRE as in your project.

It should be work now.