# Continuum Standalone - A full JDK is required But I've verified my classpath and java_home

Tags: java, continuum

Trying to run Continuum in a standalone environment.

After running the following:

> C:\Program Files\apache-continuum-1.4.1\bin>continuum console

Everything is OK until I go navigate to

```
http://localhost:8081/continuum/
```

Doing so I get the error:

```
jvm 1    | org.apache.jasper.JasperException: PWC6345: There is an error in invo
king javac.  A full JDK (not just JRE) is required
```

However, this doesn't make sense for the following reasons:

1. Typing `C:\Program Files\apache-continuum-1.4.1\bin>javac` brings up what I'd expect.

   C:\Program Files\apache-continuum-1.4.1\bin>javac -version
   javac 1.7.0_25
2. I've checked my PATH's

   JAVA_HOME: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25
   CLASSPATH: ..;\C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\bin;...

Is there something else missing?

Answer (score 0):

The CLASSPATH looks wrong (leading \ on C:, though it might be a typo). However that should not be required so I'd recommend unsetting it first to rule it out.

You should verify JAVA_HOME is correct by running %JAVA_HOME%\bin\javac. On Windows a different javac is on the path and is a system binary, so it doesn't guarantee everything else is right.

This question is likely related: [Ant "JAVA_HOME does not point to the JDK" - but it does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15098258/ant-java-home-does-not-point-to-the-jdk-but-it-does?rq=1). I think the JSP compiler uses tools.jar in the same way to invoke the compiler rather that running javac from the command line, so it has some additional suggestions to follow.