# "Unable to locate tools.jar" when running ant

Tags: java, ant, java-home, tools.jar

When running ant, I get the following message:

`Unable to locate tools.jar. Expected to find it in C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\tools.jar`

I have JAVA_HOME set to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_02`, PATH includes `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_02\bin`, CLASSPATH includes `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_02`, and ANT_HOME is set to `C:\ant`.

It seems that ant is ignoring all of these settings and looking for the tools.jar somewhere else.  There are no environment variables which point to the jre6 path.  Any ideas why?

Comment: are you sure there are no classpath settings in ant folder?

Comment: Not that I can tell, but I might be missing something.  What would I be looking for to find that?

Comment: PLease verify the JAVA_HOME path of your system environment variable... It must be like "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_12\" and try to kill all java process and try after it will run 100%.

Comment: Install JDK, Add new system variable "JAVA_HOME" to <path to Java sdk folder> and add JAVA_HOME%\bin to system variable "path"

Comment: maybe you have updated the JREs in the OS, and the addition has added in the "path" of the environment variables an entry "... / Oracle / jer" that overwrites your JAVA_HOME.
try to remove it from the "path" by leaving JAVA_HOME.

Answer (score 36):

There are two directories that looks like JDK.

```
  C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_02
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_02\
```

This may be due to both 64 bit and 32 bit JDK installed? What ever may be the case, the `java.exe` seen by **ant.bat** should from the JDK. If the JRE's `java.exe` comes first in the path, that will be used to guess the JDK location.

Put 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_02\bin' or 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_02' as the first argument in the path.

Further steps:

You can take output of `ant -diagnostics`  and look for  interesting keys. (assuming Sun/Oracle JDK).

```
 java.class.path 
 java.library.path
 sun.boot.library.path
```

(in my case tools.jar appears in java.class.path)

Comment: Thanks for the -diagnostics tip.  This shows that the `java.home` system property is pointing to the 1.6 JRE, despite all the environment variables pointing to 1.7.  Doesn't fix the problem, but it's a starting point for further investigation.

Comment: ant expects 'JDK'. The java.exe from a JDK must be appear first. See comment from Mads Hansen

Comment: I have this same error.when I have tried ant -diagnostics I got java.home : C:\Program Files\Java\jre6.But I have set JAVA_HOME to  C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_25.What is the issue

Comment: @  user1767260  : is that C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_25 first entry in the path?

Comment: No..but there is no entry for jre.

Comment: @ user1767260 : open command window and  try 'where java'.

Comment: C:\Windows\System32\java.exe
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\bin\java.exe

Comment: Any idea?I am stuck in this iisue :(

Comment: The java.exe in system32 is a dummy: See http://mindprod.com/jgloss/javaexe.html#MULTIPLES.  You can put your JDK/bin as the first entry.

Answer (score 11):

I was also having the same problem So I just removed the JDK path from the end and put it in start even before all System or Windows 32 paths.

Before it was like this:

> C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\;C:\Users\Rajkaran\AppData\Local\Smartbar\Application\;C:\Users\Rajkaran\AppData\Local\Smartbar\Application\;C:\Program Files\doxygen\bin;**%JAVA_HOME%\bin**;%ANT_HOME%\bin

So I made it like this:

> **%JAVA_HOME%\bin**;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\;C:\Users\Rajkaran\AppData\Local\Smartbar\Application\;C:\Users\Rajkaran\AppData\Local\Smartbar\Application\;C:\Program Files\doxygen\bin;%ANT_HOME%\bin

Comment: Running a command like '''where java''' which will list if java is in these other directories and taking priority over your JAVA_HOME path and which java is first. This might show which other path is messing with it. I've seen other java installs (JRE and JDK) place java also in ProgramData\Oracle and Windows\System32, so you can alternatively clean out java programs from these directories instead.

Answer (score 4):

**The order of items in the PATH matters. If there are multiple entries for various java installations, the first one in your PATH will be used.**

I have had similar issues after installing a product, like Oracle, that puts *it's* JRE at the beginning of the PATH.

Ensure that the JDK you want to be loaded is the first entry in your PATH (or at least that it appears before `C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin` appears).

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you use the root folder of the JDK.  Don't add "\lib" to the end of the path, where tools.jar is physically located.  It took me an hour to figure that one out.  Also, this post will help show you where Ant is looking for tools.jar:

[Why does ANT tell me that JAVA_HOME is wrong when it is not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1558780/why-does-ant-tell-me-that-java-home-is-wrong-when-it-is-not/1558792#1558792)

Answer (score 2):

1. Try to check it once more according to this tutorial: http://vietpad.sourceforge.net/javaonwindows.html
2. Try to reboot your system.
3. If nothing, try to run "cmd" and type there "java", does it print anything?

Comment: It might be good to give a reflection on my answer. What have you tried?

Comment: I tried all of those, with no success