# Error for ant command in cmd

Tags: java, apache, cordova, ant

I get following error when I run ant command in cmd prompt

```
 D:\>ant
Unable to locate tools.jar. Expected to find it in C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\li
b\tools.jar
Buildfile: build.xml does not exist!
Build failed
```

I have to develop a phonegap application for andriod device .

I have set `JAVA_HOME` as `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_41;`
under system variables

and `Path` as `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_41\bin`

in system variables

My ant path is `C:\Program Files\apache-ant-1.9.3\bin;` in system variables `Path`

Values in my Path System variables are as seen below

```
%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;"C:\Program Files\Common Files\EMC";C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_41\bin;D:\username-Software\Android\sdk\platforms;D:\username-Software\Android\sdk\platform-tools;C:\Program Files\apache-ant-1.9.3\bin;D:\username-Software\Android\sdk\tools;
```

Answer (score 1):

`build.xml does not exist:` did you run ant command in directory where build.xml is located? You may create it first - learn how to do it in [ant tutorial](http://ant.apache.org/manual/tutorial-HelloWorldWithAnt.html)

`tools.jar`: run `java -version`. It may happen that some other java have preference in PATH variable. You might need to fine-tune `PATH` variable. Java binary is often copied to `c:\windows` (aka `system32`). Try to add `JAVA_HOME\bin` to start of `PATH` variable

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem a year ago because i've installed two different JDK that appears in my PATH. check this

["Unable to locate tools.jar" when running ant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9119479/unable-to-locate-tools-jar-when-running-ant)

Comment: I have got this in my PATH system variables

%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;"C:\Program Files\Common Files\EMC";C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_41\bin;D:\username-Software\Android\sdk\platforms;D:\username-Software\Android\sdk\platform-tools;C:\Program Files\apache-ant-1.9.3\bin;D:\username-Software\Android\sdk\tools;

Comment: No where is two path for java\bin is set as per your post

Comment: java often is copied to c:\windows (aka system32)

Comment: Try to add JAVA_HOME\bin to start of PATH variable.

Comment: Now after adding JAVA_HOME to the start I get just 

Buildfile: build.xml does not exist!
Build failed

Comment: Well, question author accepts the answears, not responder :-). The other one is mine and there is info about build failed message with link to tutorial

Comment: Yes i can respond but your answer is better that's why i vote it up ;)