# Not able to start Tomcat using ant commands

Tags: java, batch-file, tomcat, ant

I have a tomcat folder. I am able to start tomcat using `catalina.bat run` command as well as `startup.bat` command from cmd prompt and able to access the URL: http://localhost:6080/

But I have the below setenv.bat

```
@echo off

rem - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
rem DO NOT MODIFY THE TEMPLATE FILE.  INSTEAD, COPY THIS FILE AS setenv.bat
rem AND MAKE THE NECESSARY CHANGES IN THAT FILE.
rem - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

rem - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
rem Set JAVA_HOME to a valid JDK installation dir
rem     e.g. set JAVA_HOME=C:\apps\java\1.6.0.14
rem - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25

rem - - - - - - - - - - - -  - - - - - - - - - -
rem Set ANT_HOME to a valid ANT installation dir
rem     e.g. set ANT_HOME=C:\apps\ant\1.8.2
rem - - - - - - - - - - - -  - - - - - - - - - -
set ANT_HOME=C:\my_work\DOM\DSGI\ENV_SETUP\apache-ant-1.9.4

rem - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
rem Set PATH to include bin directories from JDK and ANT
rem - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
set PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%ANT_HOME%\bin;%LIBPATH%;%PATH%

rem - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
rem Set ANT_OPTS to increase the ANT runtime memory
rem e.g. set ANT_OPTS=-Xmx1444m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
rem - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
set ANT_OPTS=-Xmx1444m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m

@echo on
```

When I am trying to start tomcat using the ant tomcat is not coming up and i am not able to access the URL.

first I executed `setenv.bat`
after that when i am doing ant start its gining the below result.

```
C:\app\scope\olm\scope-studio\mip-2015>ant start
Unable to locate tools.jar. Expected to find it in C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\tools.jar
Buildfile: C:\app\scope\olm\scope-studio\mip-2015\build.xml

-init:
     [echo] Current OS Family: windows
     [echo] ANT_HOME is set to = C:\my_work\DOM\DSGI\ENV_SETUP\apache-ant-1.9.4
     [echo] JAVA_HOME is set to = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25

start:
     [echo] MIP tomcat server instance started

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 25 seconds
```

Comment: Have you check solution in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9119479/unable-to-locate-tools-jar-when-running-ant?

Comment: I tried it not helped for me.

Comment: @Abdul, would you mind showing respective build script for review?