# Jenkins: Unable to find a javac compiler

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, ant

I'm running job in Jenkins, while running I'm getting below error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.8:run
        (deploy-artifact) on project SoapOCPTestingPOC: An Ant BuildException has occured:
        The following error occurred while executing this line:
[ERROR] C:\Arun\SoapAutomation\et-ocp-automation\build.xml:37: Unable to find a javac compiler;
[ERROR] com.sun.tools.javac.Main is not on the classpath.
[ERROR] Perhaps JAVA_HOME does not point to the JDK.
[ERROR] It is currently set to "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre"
[ERROR] around Ant part ...<ant antfile="C:\Arun\SoapAutomation\et-ocp-automation\build.xml">
        ... @ 4:69 in C:\Arun\SoapAutomation\et-ocp-automation\target\antrun\build-main.xml
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
```

I have Java home : `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181`

I have tried some possible ways. but I'm not able to figure it out.

Comment: Have you checked the related links on the right side of this page, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1558780/why-does-ant-tell-me-that-java-home-is-wrong-when-it-is-not?rq=1) one?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `JAVA_HOME` points to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre` instead of `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181`.

Set it in the environment variables

Linux: [How to set JAVA_HOME in Linux for all users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24641536/how-to-set-java-home-in-linux-for-all-users)

Windows:[How to set java_home on Windows 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619584/how-to-set-java-home-on-windows-7)

Then open a command prompt and try to print `JAVA_HOME` to check its value.

I think this should resolve your issue.

Comment: Can you paste the complete jenkins error/console log.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem on one of our build servers recently, from ant:

```
C:\BuildTools\Android\android-sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:730: Unable to find a javac compiler;
com.sun.tools.javac.Main is not on the classpath.
Perhaps JAVA_HOME does not point to the JDK.
It is currently set to "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_181"
```

This despite `SET JAVA_HOME` reporting

```
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181
```

We resolved the problem today by rebooting the server in question (Windows Server 2012 R2) so I can only advise you try the same course of action.